# Getting generated name in AWS Cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

When creating a WebAcl in CDK and letting CDK generate the name, I want to use that generated name as a variable in CDK, i.e. when generating the WebAcl like this (no explicit name set in the properties) ...

```
const webAcl = new CfnWebACL(this, "webAcl", {
  defaultAction: {
    allow: {},
  },
  scope: myScope,
  visibilityConfig: {
    cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true,
    metricName: "webACL",
    sampledRequestsEnabled: true,
  }
});
```

... the webAcl will have a generated Name like `webAcl-7xtQ0oTU473X` after deployment (the id with an appended hash). The problem is that I do not know how to reference this name as a variable in CDK.

I found the following possibilities to get some type of ids/names but none of them resolve to `webAcl-7xtQ0oTU473X` after deployment (some, however, include the value I want):

```
webAcl.name // is undefined in CDK
webAcl.logicalId // resolves to 'webAcl' (no hash)
webAcl.attrId // resolves to the id
webAcl.attrLabelNamespace // resolves to 'awswaf:<accountNumber>:webacl:webACL-7xtQ0oTU473X:'
webAcl.attrArn // resolves to the full Arn
Names.uniqueId(webAcl) // resolves to '<stackName><nestedStackName>webACL<someOtherHash>'
```

Is there some other way to get the desired value as a variable?

Comment: Try `from aws_cdk import Fn` 
`Fn.get_att()`, I'm not sure, but maybe this is a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## L1 construct's properties

> L1 constructs are exactly the resources defined by AWS CloudFormation—no more, no less. You must provide the resource's required configuration
> yourself.
>
> From the [Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_l1_using)

The library does not define any values for us but uses only the values we have provided. So, for example, if we do not set any value for the `Name`, then there is no value in the synthesized template.

Below is our resource definition from the synthesized template.

```yaml
Resources:
  webAcl:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {}
      Scope: my-scope
      VisibilityConfig:
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        MetricName: webACL
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true
```

The resource definition does not have the `Name` property. CloudFormation generates the property when it deploys the template.

There is no way to access properties we have not set. Okay, without hacks.

## L1 construct's return values

In the CloudFormation template, we can use the resource's return values. Please, find the list in the [CloudFormation user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#aws-resource-wafv2-webacl-return-values) for the WebACL. Every resource has this section.

We can access the values in the CDK script as [tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html).

```js
  console.log({
    ref: webAcl.ref,
    attrArn: webAcl.attrArn,
    attrCapacity: webAcl.attrCapacity,
    attrId: webAcl.attrId,
    attrLabelNamespace: webAcl.attrLabelNamespace
  })
```

[image]

And these are the only values generated by the CloudFormation during the deployment, which we can access in our script. The CDK library maps them nicely to the CloudFormation `GetAtt`, or `Ref` function calls in the synthesized template.

For example, we get this for the `webAcl.attrCapacity`. I have no idea why it looks weird in the console log.

```yaml
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - webAcl
          - Capacity
```

## Maybe a workaround

We can use [intrinsic functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cdk-lib#user-content-intrinsic-functions-and-condition-expressions) to extract our value from the resource's values.

```js
Fn.select(3, Fn.split(':', webAcl.attrLabelNamespace))
```

In the synthesized template, we get the chain of function calls.

```yaml
        Fn::Select:
          - 3
          - Fn::Split:
              - ":"
              - Fn::GetAtt:
                  - webAcl
                  - LabelNamespace
```

This looks fragile to me, but it might work. Please keep in mind that you can not apply any JavaScript operations to this value but use it as a construct property only. Because the CDK substitutes it with function calls in the template.

## Code for reference

I use the following code to test the answer.

```js
import { App, Fn, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { env } from 'process'
import { CfnBucket } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3'
import { CfnWebACL } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-wafv2'

function createStack (scope, id, props) {
  const stack = new Stack(scope, id, props)

  const webAcl = new CfnWebACL(stack, 'webAcl', {
    defaultAction: {
      allow: {},
    },
    scope: 'my-scope',
    visibilityConfig: {
      cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true,
      metricName: 'webACL',
      sampledRequestsEnabled: true,
    }
  })

  new CfnBucket(stack, 'bucket', {
    bucketName: Fn.select(3, Fn.split(':', webAcl.attrLabelNamespace))
  })

  console.log({
    ref: webAcl.ref,
    attrArn: webAcl.attrArn,
    attrCapacity: webAcl.attrCapacity,
    attrId: webAcl.attrId,
    attrLabelNamespace: webAcl.attrLabelNamespace
  })

  return stack
}

const app = new App()
createStack(app, 'WebAclName', {
  env: { account: env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION }
})
```